# Read a csv file, clean it, then write out the result as a csv using Apache Beam dataflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to read a csv file, clean it, then write out the result as a csv using Apache Beam dataflow. The purpose is to make the file loadable into BigQuery. The cleaning rule is to simply escape a double quote with a double quote.
My cleaning rule works. I’m having trouble incorporating it into a pipeline. I am seeking advice on what my cleaning function should return and how to call it through the pipeline.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText

lines = p | ReadFromText(file_pattern="gs://dev/clean_input/input01.csv")

def parse_method(line):
    
    CSV_PARSING_KWARGS = {
        'doublequote': True,
        'escapechar': '\\',
        'quotechar': '"',
        'delimiter': ','
    }

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, CSV_PARSING_KWARGS)
    for rec in reader:
        cw = csv.writer(out_file, escapechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        cw.writerow(rec)
        return rec
        

def run(region, project, bucket, temploc ):
    argv = [
           # Passed in args 
           '--region={}'.format(region),
           '--project={}'.format(project),
           '--temp_location={}'.format(temploc),
           # Constructs
           '--staging_location=gs://{}/clean_input/stg/'.format(bucket),
           # Mandatory constants
           '--job_name=cleammycsv',
           '--runner=DataflowRunner'     
           ]
      
    options = PipelineOptions(
    flags=argv
    )

    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
  
    clean_csv = (pipeline
    lines = lines| 'Read' >> beam.Map(parse_method)
    line = lines | 'Output to file' >> WriteToText(file_pattern="gs://dev/clean_output/output_file.csv")
    )   
    pipeline.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import argparse
   
   # Create the parser  
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the CSV cleaning pipeline')   

   parser.add_argument('-r','--region', help='Region ID where data flow job to run', default='australia-southeast1')
   parser.add_argument('-p','--project', help='Unique project ID', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-b','--bucket', help='Bucket name', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-t','--temploc', help='Bucket name and folder', required=True)
   
   # Execute the parse_args() method
   args = vars(parser.parse_args())

   run(project=args['project'], bucket=args['bucket'], region=args['region'],temploc=args['temploc'])
```

Comment: What does your current `parse_method` user function return?

Comment: The parse function writes out a file. If there is a double quote  in the data field it adds a double quote and also quotes the field e.g. "mystring""data" .

Comment: You simply have to remove the double quote before a load into BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got something working which does the job.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText


def parse_file(element):
  for line in csv.reader([element], quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL):
      line = [s.replace('\"', '') for s in line]
      clean_line = '","'.join(line)
      final_line = '"'+ clean_line +'"'
      return final_line



def run(region, project, bucket, temploc ):
    argv = [
           # Passed in args 
           '--region={}'.format(region),
           '--project={}'.format(project),
           '--temp_location={}'.format(temploc),
           # Constructs
           '--staging_location=gs://{}/clean_input/stg/'.format(bucket),
       # Mandatory constants
           '--job_name=cleammycsv',
           '--runner=DataflowRunner'     
          ]
    filename_in = 'gs://{}/clean_input/IN_FILE.csv'.format(bucket)
    files_output = 'gs://{}/clean_output/OUT_FILE.csv'.format(bucket)
    
    options = PipelineOptions(
    flags=argv
    )

    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
   

    clean_csv = (pipeline 
    | 'Read input file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(filename_in)
    | 'Parse file' >> beam.Map(parse_file)
    | 'writecsv' >> beam.io.WriteToText(files_output,num_shards=10)
   )
   
    pipeline.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import argparse
   
   # Create the parser  
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the CSV cleaning pipeline')   

   parser.add_argument('-r','--region', help='Region ID where data flow job to run', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-p','--project', help='Unique project ID', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-b','--bucket', help='Bucket name', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-t','--temploc', help='Bucket name and folder', required=True)
   
   # Execute the parse_args() method
   args = vars(parser.parse_args())

   run(project=args['project'], bucket=args['bucket'], region=args['region'],temploc=args['temploc'])
```